# Filter and Save to pdf in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, pdf

I'd like to move through a filter and print out what appears on the filtered page to a pdf file before moving onto the next filter item. The idea driving this is that I need to report school building info for each district in my state. I currently have the data sitting in a table (could easily be a pivot with a slicer if that code works out better) with filters set up as I need. The length of columns will change as the district changes to account for varying sizes. Currently, my code does not work. I need help figuring out why.

```
Sub ShiftandPrint()
Dim i As Integer
i = 1
    For cl = 1 To Columns.Count
        n = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Columns(cl))
    Next
Do While Cells(3, i).Value <> ""
    With Sheet1
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        .Range("n").AutoFilter
        .Range("n").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Cell(3, i)
    End With

Dim fName As String
With ActiveSheet
fName = .Range("A1").Value & .Range("A2").Value
.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
        "C:\My Documents\" & fName, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False,       OpenAfterPublish:=False
End With
i = i + 1
Loop
End Sub
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What's your question exactly?

Comment: Bond, what a silly thing I missed ha. My code doesn't work.  I'd like to be able to move down a filtered list and save what's displayed as a pdf for each filtered view. I'll only be moving down the contents of one column.